# Stopping NDSolver at time of error

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, error-trapping

I am using NDSolver and WhenEvent to solve a system of differential equations. I get this message:

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 49169.954923435114`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

The solution I get is pretty stable until that time, then blows off completely.
At each evaluation I get the same behaviour at different times.

I understand that the problem might lie with the fact that I am solving for very long times, and eventually the algorithm just starts having problems handling all the data.

Is there a way to stop the solver as soon as the error comes up?

Comment: Doesn't the solver already stop exactly at the point mentioned?

Comment: Maybe it does, but the solution is then just extrapolated for the remaining time. Is there a way to return the last time t before the error?  I am thinking of something like WhenEvent["error", tfinal = t]

Comment: Maybe this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/66590/breaking-out-of-ndsolve?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately the system does not hit a singularity, so I have no way to analytically identify a point where to stop the integration, like in the link. There is no way to make it stop in response to the error itself?

Comment: Let's say you have `sol = NDSolve[..., x, {t, 0, 100000}]`.  The `x["Domain"] /. sol` will yield `{{{0, 49169.954923435114}}}`, and you can get the time it stopped.  You can also use the option `NDSolve[..., "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate&}]` and the solution won't extrapolate; however, it will return `Indeterminate`, which may be good or may cause other problems.  Without explicit code, we're just guessing.

Comment: Usually, the solution already has gone bad before this error occurs.  Try plotting your solution near where `NDSolve` failed.

Comment: @MichaelE2, the "x["Domain"] /. sol" method works perfectly for me. If you write it up as an answer I can accept it.

Comment: @bbgodfrey in the body of my question it says explicitly that the solution is well behaved until the time of the error. I suspect the error comes from rounding errors as the system is an ODE but the singularity is hit at different times at each run.

Comment: @AndreaDiBiagio The OP of [(48556)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/48556) also had a problem with round-off error and `NDSolve::ndsz`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, a test case:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -1/x[t], x[0] == -1}, x, {t, 0, 2}]
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.499999735845871`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected. >>

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Consult [What's inside InterpolatingFunction[{{1., 4.}}, <>]?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/28337/whats-inside-interpolatingfunction1-4) or [InterpolatingFunctionAnatomy](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePackages.html) and you will discover that [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) comes with lots of utilities and methods that give access to a wealth of information.  In particular, the method `"Domain"` will yield the domain of the `InterpolatingFunction`, which in this case will be the interval over which `NDSolve` successfully integrated the ODE (up to the point where stiffness stopped it).

```
{tstart, tstop} = Flatten[x["Domain"] /. sol]
(*  {0.`, 0.499999735845871`}  *)
```

A couple of ways to plot.  Note for `ListLinePlot`, you don't need to know the domain; it and `ListPlot` handle `InterpolatingFunction` as a special case.

```
ListLinePlot[x /. sol]
Plot @@ {{x[t], x'[t]} /. First[sol], Flatten@{t, x["Domain"] /. sol}}
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

By default, going past the ends of the domain results in extrapolation.

```
Plot[x[t] /. First[sol], {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can use the option, mentioned in a comment in the linked question, `"ExtrapolationHandler"` to override the default extrapolation.

```
sol2 = NDSolve[{x'[t] == -1/x[t], x[0] == -1}, x, {t, 0, 10}, 
   "ExtrapolationHandler" -> {Indeterminate &}];

Plot[x[t] /. First[sol2], {t, 0, 2}]
```

> NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.4999997164125506`....

[image: Mathematica graphics]