# How to extract the time t of an interpolated function created by NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, crash, date-and-time

I'm working with the function NDSolve. I give it the time of integration, the time I want it to evaluate my differential equations. Sometimes, it crashes before the end of its attribuated time ; For example, I want to evaluate between 0 and 2000 seconds, but for a reason, it crashed at 1877.99325.... or something.

The fact that it crashed or stopped because a predicted event happened doesn't interest me here. I would like to know if there is a way to extract that time and put it in a variable, like that :

```
    NDSolve[...]
    (*output of NDSolve*){{f1[x]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1877.99325 (*it's this value that I want !*)}},<>][x],f2[x]->InterpolatingFunction[{{0.,1877.99325 (*it's this value that I want !*)}},<>][x]}}
    t=a way or an other to extract my value
    timecrash=t
```

How could I do that ? Any help would be great !

EDIT : ... OK, so my answer was deleted and transformed as a comment, and now I can't comment my own answer (which was supposed to be a comment, by the way). But I can't comment the first comments neither because I still need 50 rep (..??)
I tried the "Domain" solution, but it doesn't work so far. I tried these lines :

```
    f["Domain"]/.sol(*this "sol" comes from sol=NDSolve[...]*)//Last
```

The output is :
        f[Domain]
Another shot :
        f["Domain"]//Last
The output is :
        Domain

Comment: Letting `f` be any one of your `InterpolatingFunction[]`s, try `f["Domain"] // Last`.

Comment: what @Guesswhoitis says. also see [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/how-to-splice-together-several-instances-of-interpolatingfunction)

Comment: Mmmh nope, nothing happens. I only got the word "Domain" as an output... Could you be more specific ? Is there a package I am supposed to use ? @chuy, I am unfortunately not used to this kind of dense coding, so I don't really see where I could find any piece of answer :o)

Comment: Well, did you assign the output of `NDSolve[]` to something?

Comment: (You can comment on your own question, regardless of how much rep you have.)

Comment: It's supposed to work, but if you want to facilitate diagnosis, you might want to post in full your code that involves `NDSolve[]` so potential helpers can try things out for themselves.

Comment: @Darryl Isn't [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87525/stopping-ndsolver-at-time-of-error) the same question in essence?  (If not, please clarify the difference. Without the particular code you're using, it seems the same.)

Comment: @Guesswhoitis. The user Darryl seems to have created a duplicate account.

Comment: @Michael E2 OK, indeed this question is the same, I didn't find it when I first did a research on the questions asked. 
So it finally works, but there was a difference between my code and the code you used, Michael E2, and this difference made the "Domain" work.
The code is indeed 
        Flatten[f["Domain"] /. sol] // Last
If you write 
        NDSolve[{(*differential équations with f[x] & g[x]*)},{f[x],g[x]},{x,0,1000}]
though, it won't work. If you use instead
        NDSolve[{(*diff équations with f[x] & g[x]*)},{f,g},{x,0,1000}]

Comment: @Darryl Yes, I almost always use the form `NDSolve[eqns, {f, g}, {x,...}]` for this and other reasons. Otherwise something like `f[x] /. sol /. x -> "Domain"` would probably work. Glad you solved it. (Including such details as you mentioned in you comment about the actual call to `NDSolve` would have helped others to give you more precise and helpful advice earlier. That's why people often ask for the code.)