# How to copy a number from an error message?

Tags: differential-equations, warning-messages, error-trapping, error-propagation

Is there any way to copy a number from an error message and assign it to a variable, without manually doing it?

For instance, I am trying to solve some coupled Differential equations as follows:

```
H[a_] := Sqrt[1/(3 10^18) (B[a] 10^(-3 a) + R[a] 10^(-4 a) )] ;
eqn1 = M'[a] + 1/H[a] (1/M[a])^2;
eqn2 = R'[a] + 10^a/M[a] M'[a] B[a];
eqn3 = B'[a] - 1/M[a] M'[a] B[a];
sol1 = NDSolve[{eqn1 == 0, eqn2 == 0, eqn3 == 0, M[0] == 100, 
   R[0] == 10^50, B[0] == 10^47}, {M, R, B}, {a, 0, 15}]
```

I am getting an error message (although the equations are getting solved upto a~13.5) as :

```
NDSolve::ndsz: At a == 13.536140129488167`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
```

I want to extract the number 13.536140129488167 from the error message and assign it to variable, without manually copying and pasting it.

I need to do this since I have to run the code in some loop or vary some other parameters.

Comment: Michael E2's solution [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/243546/how-to-copy-a-particular-number-from-an-error-message#comment613070_243546) works well, doesn't it?: `(M["Domain"] /. First[sol1])[[1]]`

Comment: If you don't know what `M["Domain"]` means, check these: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/19042/1871 https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/28341/1871 For a more general solution, check [the post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20367/1871) I've already linked under your previous question.

Comment: If you're having difficulty with `/.`, `[[ ]]`, etc., please start from here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/25616/1871

Comment: [This question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87525/stopping-ndsolver-at-time-of-error/87579#87579) is superficially different, but [its answer here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87525/stopping-ndsolver-at-time-of-error/87579#87579) answers this question.  So I linked them.

Comment: Yes, M["Domain"] /. First[sol1])[[1]] works. 
I used 
Reverse[(M["Domain"] /. First[sol1])[[1]]] // First to extract the number.
Thanks.